# vue typescript emit - get value in parent

Tags: typescript, vue.js, emit

I have a small problem with vue emit. I used it about a year ago, but now in my new project, I can't do this. I spent a few hours finding solution, but I really don't know what is wrong. I can't get emitted value in the parent component.

children:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="val" outlined></v-text-field>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Emit } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class BasicInput extends Vue {
  val: string = "";

  @Emit()
  inputValue(): any {
    console.log("emit");
    return this.val;
  }
}
</script>
```

parent:

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto mt-2 mb-6" max-width="60%" outlined>
    <v-form>
      <BasicInput label="tytuł głosowania" v-on:input-value="inputValue" />
      <BasicTextarea label="skrótowy opis" />
      <BasicTextarea label="opis" />
      <BasicDatepicker />
      <AddMoreInput />
      <v-btn @click="inputValue">Zapisz</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

import BasicInput from "./subcomponents/BasicInput.vue";
import BasicTextarea from "./subcomponents/BasicTextarea.vue";
import BasicDatepicker from "./subcomponents/BasicDatepicker.vue";
import AddMoreInput from "./subcomponents/AddMoreInput.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    BasicInput,
    BasicTextarea,
    BasicDatepicker,
    AddMoreInput
  }
})
export default class AddVoting extends Vue {
  private inputValue(data: any) {
    console.log("test", data);
  }
}
</script>
```

As I remember in this situation parameter "data" event "inputValue" in the parent component should be the emitter's value. But it is a list of event parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With that code:

```
  <v-btn @click="inputValue">Zapisz</v-btn>
```

When you click on the button, it triggers the `inputValue` function, but because the event was trigger by a click, its passing the event parameters of that click.

That not what you want, you want that the input itself trigger the event.

What you can do is to trigger the event by calling the function inputValue() of the child from the parent.

You can do that by giving a reference to the child:

```
 <BasicInput
    label="tytuł głosowania"
    ref="my-input"
    v-on:input-value="inputValue"
  />
```

And create a method in the parent to emit from the child:

```
  emitEventFromInput(): void {
    this.$refs["my-input"].inputValue();
  }
```

Then you call that method when you click on your button:

```
   <v-btn @click="emitEventFromInput">Zapisz</v-btn>
```

Full code of parent (no changes for the child):

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto mt-2 mb-6" max-width="60%" outlined>
    <v-form>
      <BasicInput
        label="tytuł głosowania"
        ref="my-input"
        v-on:input-value="inputValue"
      />
      <v-btn @click="emitEventFromInput">Zapisz</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

import BasicInput from "./children.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    BasicInput,
  },
})
export default class AddVoting extends Vue {
  private inputValue(data: any) {
    console.log("val in parent =>", data);
  }
  emitEventFromInput(): void {
    this.$refs["my-input"].inputValue();
  }
}
</script>
```

It might works ! But keep in mind that is not a good practice in vue to access to child methods

A better solution (but a little bit more complex) is to create a v-model on your , by doing that you will have a two ways binding between the child and parent. See the doc to do it : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html